# Change Speech Voice in Speech API

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winforms

How do we change the voice to be used from within our apps? I cannot seem to figure out what or where the default voices are for Windows 8.

I've read articles online that say that Microsoft David is MS Windows 8's latest and greatest voice, but I have a new Windows 8 Pro system and no such voice exists on my system (only Zira and some other guy).

I am awware of [Select Voice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.selectvoice.aspx) which lets you use a string as the Name of the voice, but after trying about 30 different names, including David (and Dave), it throws an exception saying that voice does not exist.

I have tried `InstalledVoice` - but not sure how to use that.

How/where can we *download* different voices to be used with Windows Speech Recognition, and how do we select different voices to be used from within our code?

Also, `SelectVoicebyHints()` does absolutely nothing at all. I don't know why.

Comment: you can use `GetInstalledVoices()` to find all the installed voices on your system. and use `SelectVoice(voice)` to set it

Comment: Yep. I eventually figured that out. But how do I get more voices for it? I've searched everywhere and not found any. Also, how do you create your own?

Answer (score 1):

The SpeechSynthesizer has a GetInstalledVoices method which returns a ReadOnlyCollection of Voices installed in your system (InstalledVoice type), in order to change the synthesizer voice you should call the SelectVoice Method in which requires the voice name(String type)

```
SpeechSynthesizer synt = new SpeechSynthesizer();
IReadOnlyCollection<InstalledVoice> InstalledVoices = synt.GetInstalledVoices();
InstalledVoice InstalledVoice = InstalledVoices.First();
synt.SelectVoice(InstalledVoice.VoiceInfo.Name);
synt.Speak("This is how you select an installed voice");
```

To see what voices are installed in your computer you can see them in:
Control Painel -> Speech Recognition -> Text to Speech
You can specify more info there as well like voice speed

if you want to add more voices to your computer you should search some company like

- Ivona - http://www.ivona.com/us/for-individuals/voices-for-windows/

Not sure but SelectVoicebyHints should try to selected any voice from those installed where is more alike to the specifications that you passed through the method